# Invision Mobile screen display issue on Iphone

Tags: interface-design, user-experience, invision-studio

There is extra space left on my mobile screen which is not there on my Invision screen on Mac.

As you can see the below image is from Invision Studio on Mac. The width is 320px but when i check on mobile i see extra white space on right.

[image]

As you can see the below screen of Mobile. My screen is not stopping till the blue rectangle. It is showing extra part to the right.
I[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your UI must be the same size as your phone. For example if you are using iPhone Se As a reference for your design which is **320 x 568**, and you are previewing your design on a iPhone 8 (**375 x 667**) you would see some extra white space.

The reason is that the software you are using (sketch, invision etc...) is mirroring the artboard with the exact dimensions used in design and that's why you are seeing some extra white space on your screen.

**Solution :**

Try to change your artboard size or use another cell phone to your design.